# Error with cursor in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the next error in the next Script with cursor in MySQL.
"Script line: 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare c_salari cursor for select salario from empleados;

open c_salari;

' at line 10
"

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `empresa`.`EmpleatsRang` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `empresa`.`EmpleatsRang` (valor_inicial int, valor_final int) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
declare i int default 0;
declare resultat int default 0;
declare totalemp int;
declare v_salario int;
declare c_salari cursor for select salario from empleados;

select count(*) into totalemp from empleados;

open c_salari;

while i<totalemp do
  fetch c_salari into v_salario;
  if salari >= valor_inicial and salari <= valor_final then
    resultat=resultat+1;
  end if;
  i=i+1;
end while;

close c_salari;
return resultat;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why select all salarios into cursor when you are only interested in a range (which in turn means that your loop is doing more than it needs to), You have no error checking valor_inicial , valor_final to validate that you can do anything sensible, while you can use a counter to exit the loop a handler is the more usual approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All declare statement should come after begin itself and before any select .
so write

```
Declare c_salari cursor for select salario from empleados;
```

before

```
select count(*) into totalemp from empleados;
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because of i don't put set into variable "i" and variable "resultat"

```
while i<totalemp do
  fetch c_salari into v_salario;
  if salari >= valor_inicial and salari <= valor_final then
    set resultat=resultat+1; /*Need set*/
  end if;
  set i=i+1; /*Need set*/
end while;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a cursor for such simple task. Use SELECT instead.

```
select count(salario)
from empleados
where salari >= valor_inicial and salari <= valor_final
```

The rule of thumb say: if it is possible, use one SQL statement. If not, use more SQL statements. The cursor is the last option and it kills DBMS performance.

Comment: I need to use cursor, because it is for an exercise

Answer (score 0):

please use semicolon after end while